# How do I download my model using wget so that I can upload it to streamlit?

Tags: python, wget, streamlit

I saved my emotion detection model as a .h5. It's too big to be uploaded to Github so i uploaded it to dropbox and used wget to download the model, so that I can deploy it to streamlit. This is my code:

```py
if not os.path.exists("models/emotion_detection_model_for_streamlit.h5"):
    with st.spinner("Loading model..."):
        os.system("wget --no-check-certificate -O 
models/emotion_detection_model_for_streamlit.h5 \"link-to-model"")

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("models/emotion_detection_model_for_streamlit.h5")
```

When deploying the app via streamlit, I am getting the following error:
[link to error message from streamlit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWHFw.png)

[manager] Python dependencies were installed from /app/emotion-in-motion-2/requirements.txt using pip.
[manager] Processed dependencies!
2022-02-11 10:34:22.712519: W tensorflow/stream executor/platform/default/do loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0';
dlerror: libel
2022-02-11 10:34:22.712601: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
sh: 1: wget: not found
2022-02-11 10:34:25.828 Uncaught app
exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py"
line 350, in
*run_script
exec (code, module.*
*dict*_)
File "/app/emotion-in-motion-2/app.py", line 30, in 
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("models/emotion_detection_model_for_streamlit.h5")
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py",
line 67, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered _tb) from None
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/saving/save.py"
line 204, in load model
raise I0Error (f'No file or directory found at {filepath_str}')
OSError: No file or directory found at models/emotion _detection_model_for_streamlit.h5
[client] Connecting...
sh: 1: wget: not found
2022-02-11 10:34:33.564 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last) :
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py"
line 350, in
*run_script
exec (code, module.
*dict*.
File
"/app/emotion-in-motion-2/app.py"
, line 30.
in
«module>
model
=tf.keras.models.load_model("models/emotion_detection_model_for_streamlit.h5")
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py",line67,inerror_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/saving/save.py",line 204, in load model
raise I0Error (f' No file or directory found at {filepath_str}'
OSError: No file or directory found at models/emotion_detection* model_for_streamlit.h5

Please help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `wget` command is not found. You could try to use `curl` instead.

Comment: Is there any way I can fix this using wget itself?

Comment: @SamriddhiBhrdwaj you need to install `wget` wherever you are using it. Would it be possible to include the error message as text and not as an image?

Comment: I imported wget and added it as a requirement too. Also, I've added the error message in the post now, it's quite long though

Comment: Maybe give the full path for the wget command?